# How can i make this script multi-threaded

Tags: go

the way i am using the code is passing a list of urls from a file and running each url with my code, the code uses bufio, so i can pipe the urls from the file.

command : cat test2.txt | ./mygofile

```
https://beap.adss.yahoo.com/
https://id.answers.yahoo.com/search
https://brokenurl
https://id.answers.yahoo.com/KnowledgeSearchService
https://id.answers.yahoo.com/question/nextQuestion
```

contents of sample URL

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "crypto/tls"
)

func main() {
    tr := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
    tr.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}

    passedUrl := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    var pUrl string
    for passedUrl.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(passedUrl.Text())
        if strings.Contains(passedUrl.Text(), "://"){
            pUrl = passedUrl.Text()
        } else {
            pUrl = "https://" + passedUrl.Text()
        }

        body := "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"

        req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", pUrl, bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(body)))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8")
        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue // stop here and process next item
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()

    }
}
```

The problem is that the code is very slow when i give a huge list of urls. Is there any way i can make the code multi-threaded or faster in a simple way

Comment: i want to pass around 1000's of URLS to it..

Comment: A small note on terminology: that's not a script. Go is a compiled language. "scripts" are not compiled.

Comment: @CeriseLimón could you tell me how i can do that please?

Comment: @CeriseLimón i hope it looks good now? i edited the code in the question.. 
Could you help me how i can get the script to be multi-threaded ? i don't know if is the correct term used in GO..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create pool of worker goroutine.  The worker goroutine gets urls to process from channel and exits when channel is closed. The main goroutine feeds urls to the channel and closes channel when done.

```
tr := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
tr.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}

var wg sync.WaitGroup
work := make(chan string)
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    wg.Add()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for pUrl := range work {
            fmt.Println(purl)
            if !strings.Contains(purl, "://") {
                pUrl = "https://" + passedUrl.Text()
            }

            body := "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"

            req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", pUrl, strings.NewReader(body))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                continue
            }

            req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8")
            resp, err := client.Do(req)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                continue // stop here and process next item
            }

            // do something with resp

            resp.Body.Close()

        }
    }()
}

passedUrl := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for passedUrl.Scan() {
    work <- passedUrl.Text()
}
close(work) // signal workers to exit
wg.Wait()   // wait for workers to exit
```

Comment: # command-line-arguments
./mygofile.go:23:12: not enough arguments in call to wg.Add
 have ()
 want (int)
./mygofile.go:27:26: undefined: purl
./mygofile.go:28:35: undefined: purl
./mygofile.go:29:38: undefined: passedUrl

Comment: could someone please help

Comment: pass 1 as the parameter to wg.Add